# Rest spec- Return json structure for list of parameters

Tags: json, rest, restful-architecture, wcf-rest

We have a specific business requirement:

1) Expose a rest end point which accepts a list of id's

2) Lets say we request 10 ids,

- If there is valid data for all 10 id's return an json array of the data
- If there are data issues for some, there should be an option to return the reason for the invalid state. eg:  7 valid data and 3 invalid data- return json array of 7 valid id's and for the invalid one's return error messages.

These are the options that we are looking at

Option 1:

```
{
 "elements":[
 {"id":"valA", "name":"value", "regid":"value"}
 ,{"id":"valB", "name":"value", "regid":"value"}
 ,{"id":"valc", "name":"value", "regid":"value"}
 ],
 "invaliddata":[
 {"id":"valD", "Invalidreason":"id not found"},
 {"id":"valE", "invalidReason":"registration not found"}
 ]
}
```

If all the id's have valid data we return an empty array for the invaliddata array.

Qn: If there are no id's matching, in this case should we return a 404 or should it be 200 with all id's in invaliddata array?

Option 2.
Send custom response in the the response header. The header will contain invalid id's
Qn: Will this be easier for the client to read from the header vs  body

Option 3. 
Accept only 1 id with each request, if id is not found return a 404, if id has invalid data return 404 with error message.
Qn: Is 404 a valid response for a invalid data? (Since the id is there, its technically not content not found)

Comment: You shouldn't send a 404 on a collection/bulk because you ask for several resources. 404 is use for a resource not found, if you have invalid data, you can send a 400. Your 1st option is a good one. Depends of how do you handle that data later. Maybe you can also send all results in the "elements" key. Invalid object will have the InvalidReason

Comment: We didnt want to mix invalid reason with valid data becase, for invalid data rest of the valid properties will have to be always set to empty.